# Attempting to create a quick jQuery drop down menu

Tags: jquery, menu, drop-down-menu, fadein, fadeout

am not sure if I'm doing this right, but I'm trying to create a simple drop down menu in jQuery. I basically want a div (with links) to appear once the menu item is hovered over..

**The Menu:**

```
<ul id="mainlevel">
  <li><a href="#" class="mainlevel_home" ><span>Home</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="mainlevel_feature-writers" ><span>Feature Writers</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="mainlevel_fantasy-killed-my-hsc" ><span>Fantasy Killed My HSC</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

**The Hidden Div:**

```
<div class="subMenu"><a href="/feature-writers/jd-ormsby" class="sublevel jd-ormsby"><span>J.D. Ormsby</span></a></div>
```

**The jQuery:**

```
$(".mainlevel_feature-writers").hover(function(){ 
  $(".subMenu").fadeIn("slow"); 
}, function() { 
  $(".subMenu").fadeOut("slow"); 
});
```

Now, this fades in the hidden div and fades it out fine, but - how do I stop it from fading out if someone hovers on something inside the newly shown div?

Sorry if this is a really obvious question.. I am still learning! :)

Comment: A menu isn't a trivial thing to do well, do right and do cross-browser. I'd strongly suggest you use superfish() or another jQuery or CSS menu.

Comment: I tried using the Joomla superfish component, but I was having issues with styling the individual menus (each menu item has a specific image).. so I'm using the joomla ext. menu but the drop-downs were playing up, hense me trying to write it myself :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to separate the handling of `mouseover` and `mouseout` events.

Presumably, you want the `mouseover` handler to be attached to the "top level" menu element, and the `mouseout` handler to be attached to the hidden "dropdown" div (with some state code to manage conflicts).

Comment: yes.. basically the only item that will display the hidden div is .mainlevel_feature-writers which will have multiple links inside it, I just want the fadeout to wait if the cursor is inside the hidden div.. if that makes sense :)